# What happened if I disable `Wake for Wi-Fi network access`?

Tags: network, wifi, sleep-wake

I already read this [Why does my WiFi disconnect when my Mac goes to sleep](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-WiFi-disconnect-when-my-Mac-goes-to-sleep) and this [What is the “wake for wifi network access” setting in energy preferences?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/73764/what-is-the-wake-for-wifi-network-access-setting-in-energy-preferences). Some answers contradict each other. Some people think disabling this option will make wifi never disconnect. and Some people think disabling this option will save energy, thus disconnect when sleep. Which one is correct?

Why do I care? I just want my wifi connect all the time unless I shutdown the machine. The current observation is that when the screen is off for some time, my networking apps are all disconnected. But the weird thing is I can still ping my macos from another computer. How can that happen? The wifi is on, but all my apps stop working. How may I avoid this failure of my applcations?

Comment: Please, what is *your* question?

Comment: I tried to simplify your question, so as to get answers. Feel free to kill my modifications.

Comment: Is your actual setting: "wake for wifi network access"?

Comment: @danielAzuelos whatever. I don't care of this question anymore. thanks a lot for taking time to edit my question.

Comment: If you don't care about this question anymore, then why not just delete it.

Comment: Did you find either an explanation or a fix?

Comment: Please, dont care that much of people who downvote and don't participate. That's the human fate: too many watchers not enough to do real thing.

Comment: @user3439894 The reason why I don't delete it because this post represents the shame of those people who downvoted other people's questions and answers. Cheers.

Comment: @danielAzuelos thanks a lot for your kind help. My thought: 1) After some tests (suggested by the deleted answer), I find out if the option `Wake for wiki` is disabled, the wifi'll be off when os in sleep. If the option is enabled, wifi'll be on in sleep. Thus the first link's answer is wrong. 2) reason why I can ping the ip in sleep is because (a) the option is enabled. (b) os tries to remain network for services. 3) reason why my apps are disconnected even if the wifi is on is because os stops apps to save energy. The above are just my thought. How to avoid apps being put to sleep? no idea.

Comment: @danielAzuelos just FYI, I posted my own answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I did some tests suggested by a deleted answer.

(1) If I disable `Wake for Wi-Fi network access` and put macos to sleep mode, the wifi will be off. (I can not ping the wifi's ip anymore in another client.)

(2) If I enable `Wake for Wi-Fi network access` and put macos to sleep mode, the wifi will remain on. (I can ping the wifi's ip successfully in another client.) But even if the wifi is on, my apps will still be disconnected.

Thus, the answer in [link:  Why does my WiFi disconnect when my Mac goes to sleep](https://www.quora.com/Why-does-my-WiFi-disconnect-when-my-Mac-goes-to-sleep):

```
After a certain time frame, more processes are frozen for the system to save energy.

Disable “Wake for network access” and you shouldn’t have this problem anymore.
```

The first sentence should be correct. The reason why my apps are disconnected even if the wifi is on is because my apps are frozen when the system is in sleep mode.

But the second sentence is incorrect. Disable the option doesn't solve that problem at all and even make wifi become off in sleep mode.

### How to avoid apps disconnecting from network?

Avoid macos switching to sleep mode.

### How to stop macos switching to sleep mode on power adapter when locking the screen or display is off?

System Preferences --> Energy Saver --> Power Adapter -->

- Enable `Prevent computer from sleeping automatically when the display is off`
- Disable `Put hard disks to sleep when possible`.

### How to stop macos switching to sleep mode on battery when locking the screen or display is off?

System Preferences --> Energy Saver --> Power Adapter --> Disable `Put hard disks to sleep when possible`.

and then execute the following to disable sleep mode:

```
sudo pmset -b sleep 0; sudo pmset -b disablesleep 1
```

This command is untested yet by me and referenced from [link](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/219885/use-caffeinate-to-prevent-sleep-on-lid-close-on-battery)